# How to get the Lightning Bundle NAME in controllerJS or helperJS?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

The internet wasn't too kind to me this time. [This is all I could find](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_ids.htm). So:

I know it is possible to get the runtime generated unique ***Id*** of the corresponding component like so:

```
var globalId = component.getGlobalId();
```

But, is it possible to get the ***name*** of the component programmatically in JS? That is, if my component is called 'ProjectView.cmp', the method should return 'ProjectView'.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can simply use [getName()](http://documentation.auraframework.org/auradocs#reference?topic=api:Component) method.

it returns the component's code-compatible camelCase name, e.g. 'cProjectView'

so if you want to get name without your custom namespace:

```
var cmpName = component.getName(); 
cmpName = cmpName.substr(1);
//ProjectView
```

if you want to get name with namespace:

```
var cmpName = component.getType();
//c:ProjectView
```

Comment: Thanks for the aura framework documentation. Didn't even know something like that existed!